# How to conditionally output to sidebar of each author's archive and posts by each author?

Tags: author, conditional-tags

Specifically, I am trying to conditionally hook a testimonial rotator into the sidebar of specific author archives and single posts for each specific author.

Although I am using a specific example below, the general answer I need is how to conditionally check if I am on an author archive or single post by that author and set a unique string to be used in another part of the code.

In non-code language here's what I'm after:

If on author-1 archive, or on a single post by author-1, $var = x.

If on author-2 archive, or on a single post by author-2, $var = y.

Pointers as to why my code isn't working would be appreciated.

The result of my function below is not as expected, it returns the last author's data  (in this case author-2) into all author archive and post sidebars, no matter which author archive or who the single post author is.

Here is what I am working with:

```
add_action ('genesis_before_sidebar_widget_area','user_testimonials',10); // Genesis action hook.

function user_testimonials(){

global $post;

$author_id = $post->post_author; //Get the ID of the current author

$authornicename = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', $author_id ); //get the author nicename by ID 

if (is_author() || is_singular('post')){ // First make sure we are on an author archive or a single post.

if (is_author('author-1') || $authornicename ='author-1' ){$rotatorid=445;} 

//Here I have manually looked up and inserted the author nice-name into is_author()
//The expected result would be to return true if we are on that author's archive page
//Next I checked the value of $authornicename against a manually inserted and known nice-name. 
//This should return true when on a single post by that author.
//The last part manually sets the $rotatorid to the known ID of the rotator that I want to display to be used to dynamically generate the output.

if (is_author('author-2') || $authornicename ='author-2' ){$rotatorid=451;}

echo "<section class='widget'><h3 class='widget-title'> Testimonials </h3>";
echo do_shortcode('[testimonial_rotator id='. $rotatorid .' hide_title="true" format="list"]') . '</section>';

//A shortcode is used to output the testimonial rotator.
//$rotatorid is inserted to dynamically output the rotator for that author. 
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As often the case, asking the question reveals the answer:

Use global $authordata;. Fix php errors: == operator. Fix $rid='445', not $rid=445.

Here's the working code:

```
add_action ('genesis_before_sidebar_widget_area','user_testimonials',10);

function user_testimonials(){

if (is_author() || is_singular('post')){ 

global $authordata; //using global $authordata is more direct

$authorlogin = $authordata->user_login;

//print_r( $authordata ); //to see everything

if (is_author('author-1') || ($authorlogin=="author-1") ) //Fix the == operators

{

$rid='445';

} 

elseif (is_author('author-2')  || ($authorlogin=='author-2') )

{

    $rid='451';

}


echo "<section class='widget'><h3 class='widget-title'> Testimonials </h3>";
echo do_shortcode('
[testimonial_rotator id='. $rid .' hide_title="true" format="list"]')  
. '</section>';
}
}
```